# If $n = \frac{ab}{c}$ with $n, a, b, c$ positive integers, $a \gt c$ and $b \gt c$. Is it true that $n$ is not prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Is the following statement true? And if so, how can one prove it?

*Let $n$ be an integer, $n \gt 1$.

Assume that there exist three postive integers $a, b, c$ with $ a \gt c$ and $b \gt c$  such that
$$n = \frac{ab}{c}$$
Then n is not a prime number*.

I am pretty sure that one possible solution is to resort to the prime factorization of numbers (of either $a, b$ and $c$) but I would also appreciate a more elegant solution that does not rely on this idea.

Comment: What is "not convincing enough" with the answer already posted? It is correct....

Comment: Or perhaps more to the point, I imagine it is hard to show a number is prime without relying on prime factorization...

Comment: "I am pretty sure that one possible solution is to resort to the prime factorization of numbers  but I would also appreciate a more elegant solution that does not rely on this idea".   So .... you want to prove a statement about prime factorization that does not rely upon the concept of prime factorization.

Comment: Okay, reading the comments on the answer it seems the OP was, and still is, unfamiliar with [enter link description here][1]Euclid's Lemma


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma

Comment: Ok, I forgot Euclid's lemma (or never heard of it)

Comment: Euclid's Lemma is the statement: if $p$ is prime and $p$ divides $ab$ then $p$ must divide either $a$ or $b$.  It's *very* fundamental.

Comment: So if $n =\frac {ab}c$ then $c =\frac {ab}n$ and $n|ab$.  If $n$ is not composite than $n$ is prime. ANd if $n$ is prime then $n\mid a$ or $n\mid b$.  But if $n$ divides either of those the result is a positive integer.  So either $c = \frac an b; \frac ac=k$ is a positive integer $\ge 1$ or $c =a\frac bn; \frac bn=j$ is a positive integer $\ge 1$. Those contradict $c>a; c>b$.  That is *all* in the very convincing answer.

Comment: I suppose you also need to know that if $k$ is a positive integer then $k \ge 1$ and that if $a > 0$ then $ak \ge a$. ($m < n$ and $c>0\implies mc < nc$ is a given axiom.  So if $a >0$ and $k \ge a$ then $ak \ge a\cdot 1 = a$.)

Answer (score 6):

You can aim for a contradiction. Write $$cn=ab$$

If $n$ were prime it divides either $a$ or $b$. Without loss of generality let $n\mid a$, then $$c=\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)b$$ This is a contradiction as $b>c$.

Comment: I think you just write $p$ instead of $n$ Is this right ?

Comment: @Julien Yes, thank you! Fixed.

Comment: Can you justify the statement : `If n were prime it divides either a or  b`?

Comment: @Julien Suppose it is not true for a prime $p$. Then you may write $a=a'x, b=b'y$ where $xy=p$ and $x,y<p$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: I still don't get it. I guess that one has to use the prime factorization of numbers in some form

Comment: "Can you justify the statement : If n were prime it divides either a or  b? "  That's Euclid's Lemma. It should be the first or second thing taught in *any* number theory class.

Comment: "I guess that one has to use the prime factorization of numbers in some form"  Considering "composite"  means "not prime" means "not not factorable" means "factorable" it seems perverse to think you could *avoid* prime factorization.

Comment: I will not accept this answer since it relies on Euclid's lemma and it did not cite this lemma explicitly

Answer (score 1):

As $c<\min(a,b)$, then $n\le\max(a,b)$ implies that $cn<\min(a,b)\max(a,b)=ab$.

Therefore we have that $n>\max(a,b)$

As $n$ prime implies that it is only divisible by $1$ and itself, neither $a$ or $b$ would divide $n$, therefore from

$$\frac{cn}{a}=b$$

we would have $a$ divides $c$ but $a>c$ ad so this is impossible.

Therefore $n$ is not prime.

Comment: It's not clear, can you use implications instead of "otherwise"

Comment: Is this any clearer?

Comment: How $n>\max(a,b)$ implies that $n$ is not prime

Comment: That depends on how you have defined 'prime'. $ab$ can't contain the larger $n=p$ as a factor for example.

Comment: @JMP And this last argument requires Euclid's lemma, which the OP doesn't accept as an answer ... ! (for reasons obscure to me)

Comment: I didn't say that I don't accept Euclid's lemma as an answer. I _prefered_ a solution that didn't require a direct use of prime factorisation. I don't know if the proof of Euclid's lemma requires prime factorisation

Answer (score 0):

The [proof of Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#Proof) does not require prime factorization. A consequence of this theorem is Gauss' lemma, which is the following generalization of Euclid's lemma:

> If $a,b,c$ are three integers such that $a | bc$ and $a$ is prime to $b$, then $a|c$.

Indeed, given the situation of the lemma, by Bézout's identity there exists some integers $u,v$ such that $au + bv = 1$. Multiply this identity by $c$ to deduce that $c = auc + bcv$. Now, $a$ divides $auc$ and $bcv$, so that $a$ divides their sum, that is $c$.

So far, nowhere did we use prime factorization.

Now, the proof just goes as written in the first answer. Assume towards a contradiction that $n$ is prime. If $n$ is prime to $a$ then $n$ divides $b$ by Gauss' lemma. The identity
$$c = \left(\frac{b}{n}\right)a$$
then contradicts the fact that $c < a$.

Otherwise, $n$ is not prime to $a$. It means that there exists a common divisor $d>1$ to both $n$ and $a$. Since $n$ is prime, we must have $d=n$. Thus, $n$ divides $a$. The identity
$$c = \left(\frac{a}{n}\right)b$$
then contradicts the fact that $c < b$.

Comment: Way too complicated

Comment: @Julien It's convoluted (not complicated) because you refused the straightforward answer in the first place...